# How can I search for a string prefix stored in an array of text?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to model a list of users with associated permissions the following way:

```
project = {
  id: 'some-id',
  users: ['user1:owner', 'user2:viewer', 'user3:collaborator']
}
```

I know that this can be solved with a permissions table and a `JOIN` statement.

I was wondering if this can be achieved in a performant way using an index and only one table. I am asking for both index and SQL statement to search if someone is part of a project regardless of their role.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS project (
  id TEXT DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() PRIMARY KEY,
  users TEXT[] NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}'
) WITH OIDS;
```

Thanks

P.S. Again, I know this is not "how you should do it", I am just curious if this is even possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is an abominable design, but you can try to abuse [Full Text Search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-textsearch.html) features to do it.

```
create index on project using gin (array_to_tsvector(users));
select * from project where array_to_tsvector(users) @@ 'user1\::*';
```

The first `:`, which needs to be escaped, is to match the literal colon in the string, to prevent 'user1' from matching 'user10', for example.  The second `:` is part of the syntax for full-text searching and must precede the partial match operator `*`.  If the true value of 'user1' can contain other special characters, you will have to put some work into escaping them.

This is horrible, please don't do this.